# Algolia's nbHits not working with if condition in angular

Tags: angular, algolia, instantsearch.js

I am using algolia in angular. I have to show view more button only when I have more than 8 records. I'm trying to use nbHits in if condition but it is not working.
Here is what I done so far -

```
<ais-instantsearch [config]="productsConfig">
    <ais-configure [searchParameters]="{ hitsPerPage: 8 }"></ais-configure>
    <ais-hits>
       <ng-template let-hits="hits">
             <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                   <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-2">
                         <div class="title">
                            Products
                         </div>
                      </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <ais-stats>
                                 <a href="" class="btn-view-more btn btn-info float-right" *ngIf="hits.nbHits > 8">View All</a>   
                                 {{hits.nbHits}} results found in {{hits.processingTimeMS}}ms.
                            </ais-stats>
                          </div>
                   </div>
                   <section>
                       <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-2"*ngFor="let hit of hits">
                                <figure>
                                   <img src="{{hit.picture}}" class="figure-img img-fluid">
                                   <figcaption class="">{{hit.productName}}</figcaption>
                                </figure>
                             </div>
                       </div>    
                   </section>
                </div>
             </div>
         </ng-template>
    </ais-hits>
</ais-instantsearch>
```

How to use nbHits with if condition?
Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an `<ng-template>` in your `<ais-stats>` widget to access its state.

```html
<ais-stats>
  <ng-template let-state="state">
    {{state.nbHits}} results found in {{state.processingTimeMS}}ms.
    <button *ngIf="state.nbHits > 8">View All</button>
  </ng-template>
</ais-stats>
```

You can pass a click handler that takes `nbHits` and updates the search parameter's `hitsPerPage` property with it. Here's a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-currying-4u2rd?file=/src/app/app.component.html).

Please note that for performance reasons, Algolia won't return more than 1,000 hits per API call, even if you set `hitsPerPage` to a greater number. You can change [`paginationLimitedTo`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/paginationLimitedTo/) at the index level if you want to go further than 1,000 hits, but this isn't recommended as it impacts performance. Also note that disabling the limit doesn't guarantee that you will get to the end of the hits, only that Algolia will go as far as possible in the index to retrieve results in a reasonable time.

Also note that trying to render 1,000 hits at once may slow down your app. It's usually better to go with an [infinite scrolling pattern](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/resources/ui-and-ux-patterns/in-depth/infinite-scroll/angular/), which Angular InstantSearch provides out of the box with `<ais-infinite-hits>`.